# Eclipse Velocity and xml formatting

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor, velocity

I am generating an XML document in Velocity templates. Does anyone know if there is a way to have Eclipse do the proper formatting and identation of both velocity commands and xml? At the moment I can have either-or situation: it's only xml that is being formatted or #if/#else/#end velocity commands, depending on what editor I use, but not both.

Thanks

Comment: I dont think there is such a functionality. It would also be impossible to fully validate the xml, as the #if.. would invalidate the xml anyway.

Comment: Yes, I think it makes sense. Darn it :) I would guess that having Velocity editor edit the files would the best option in that case.